# Form closing error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# for form applications. My problem is, after form closing, can not stopped on task manager?

My code:

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Gerçekten programı kapatmak istiyor musunuz?", "Closing event", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dr == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
        e.Cancel = false;
}
```

Like this:

[image: http://u1312.hizliresim.com/1j/b/vdbqd.png]

Comment: There may be some non-background threads running - which will prevent the app to exit. You might have to look into those. Attach a debugger and see if any threads are still running after form closed.

Answer (score 2):

Closing your form does not mean that your application will terminate.
Form3_FormClosing just does what it says: it closes a form. If you have other forms opened, the application will not terminate.

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Gerçekten programı kapatmak istiyor musunuz?", "Closing event", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dr == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
        // Here's what you need.
        Application.Exit();

       //or Environment.Exit() but not recommended would just kill the process. If some form has e.g. unsaved changes it would not have any chances to ask the user if he wants to save them. Also resources (database connections etc.) could not be released properly, files might not be flushed etc. 

       //Environment.Exit()
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `Application.Exit()` in FormClosing?  That doesn't make sense.  I didn't downvote, but I don't get this answer.  I don't really understand the question either.

Comment: for the simple reason  the  form is a form3  which  means  it's not the mainform clear ?   So the application  is running  with another form  for this reason  he should call  application.exit

Comment: -1. The `Application.Exit()` should not be called within the form closing. If the the form closes but the application doesn't then, there is another form opened and `Application.Exit` will close that form (it shouldn't be managed that way at all).

Another reason not to exit the application. It is form 3.

Comment: @Scott this edit is invalid as it modifies the code for no reason. If with no brackets works perfectly if there is a single instruction in it.

Comment: I see, `Form3` is a creative catch.  Horrible question.  +1 for figuring out what they are even talking about.

Comment: @phadaphunk - My edit was actually to clean up the formatting is all.  I added the braces while I was doing that, just to give it some space for easier readability.  The code doesn't change.

Comment: @Scott Just so you know this subject is being discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211011/should-we-allow-code-touch-up-for-syntaxic-sugar) as we speak.

Comment: @phadaphunk - I don't go in to edit someone's code just to change braces.  If you look at the original answer, the indentions were off.  There's nothing more annoying to look at than code that isn't aligned properly.  It takes little effort to simply format your code for the sake of future visitors.

Comment: @Scott It annoys me too. And even if you corrected every word in the post, you still shouldn't touch the code. If you really want to touch the code, you should ask the OP first in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance of `Form3` is your main form, meaning if `Application.Run()` was called with an instance of `Form3`, then generally process will exit on closing that form.

If `Form3` is not your main form, it means the main form is hidden, not closed.

---

Another reason I have seen a program still lurking behind has been due to a custom foreground thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread( someMethodWithALoop );
t.Start();
```

The process will not exit if this thread is running. You can resolve it by marking the thread as background.

```
Thread t = new Thread( someMethodWithALoop );
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

However, if you have some code like that, a better practice would be to use a `Timer`.